# How to remove the keyboard in Windows 7 when it doesn't allow me to do it in a regular way?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Look at the picture below then you can see the remove button is gray out so I can not remove it in a regular way. Any trick to remove it ?

[image]

Comment: Is the the keyboard which is actually selected (and in use) at the monent you are trying to remove it ?

Comment: Seem to be. It's always selected.

Comment: Can you remove it if you set another language/keyboard as default. (See also http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/cannot-remove-the-default-english-us-keyboard-from/d8f34045-b64a-47f3-b489-37ef96efe83a )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the services related to the Default Input Language.

In your example, that's what's going on.

Change the Default Input Language to something else, and you should then be able to remove the keyboard in question.